# How to change the color of an svg image

Tags: html, css, svg

Is there a way to change the color of an SVG image without using a third-party index like font-awesome?

I have a simple menu button below that I would like the change the color of it on hover without having to call a new image.

Is this possible?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5n8c5axr/3/)

```css
#mobile-button {
 background-image: url("https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mbkitsystems/menu.svg");
    background-size: 30px 30px;
 float: right;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 margin-right: 5%;
 margin-top: 15px;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: ease 0.3s;-webkit-transition: ease 0.3s;
}
#mobile-button:hover {
 /*background-image: url("");*/
 transition: ease 0.3s;-webkit-transition: ease 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div id="mobile-button"></div>
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to inline the svg? That will give you the most control and save you an extra request.

Comment: @JesseKernaghan Are you referring to changing it from a background image to a normal image?

Comment: yes its possible in SVG i.e using `d` attribute in svg and possible to make hover `svg:hover`.. You can refer this https://codepen.io/luiscarvalho/pen/hJFrx

Comment: @HameedBasha I don't have it in the html, it is just an svg image. I wasn't sure how that aspect of it worked.

Answer (score 3):

If you can generate an html svg element from the svg file you can use the color, and fill css properties.

```css
h1{
  color: red;
}

svg {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  fill: currentColor;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 32 32">
    <path class="path1" d="M22 20c-2 2-2 4-4 4s-4-2-6-4-4-4-4-6 2-2 4-4-4-8-6-8-6 6-6 6c0 4 4.109 12.109 8 16s12 8 16 8c0 0 6-4 6-6s-6-8-8-6z"></path>
  </svg>
  Call me
</h1>
```

If you use a div or image the most you could do is use [filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) to change the color of the element. Insert an image with a color and use grayscale/hue-rotate to change it's colors

```css
img{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  filter: hue-rotate(90deg)
  
}
```

```html
<img src='https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/firefox-logo.svg'>
```

Comment: Adobe Illustrator can export your svg files to html